# Toolbar custom position

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a problem after updating magento from 1.7 to 1.9 custom toolbar doesn't show up. I have a custom position for toolbar and it  should appear in breadcrumbs block.
Code of local.xml

```
<catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="toolbar_only" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar_only.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml"></block>    
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <name>product_list_toolbar</name>
                </action>
            </block>            
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="toolbar_only" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar_only.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml"></block>    
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <name>product_list_toolbar</name>
                </action>
            </block>            
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
```

In breadcrumbs.phtml `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('toolbar_only'); ?>`
And in toolbar_only.phtml getToolbarHtml() ?> var_dump return empty string.
I tried another way to output toolbar block

```
<?php 
// lets get the toolbar block
$toolbar = $this->getChild('product_list')->getToolbarBlock();
// add the product collection
$toolbar->setCollection($this->getChild('product_list')->getLoadedProductCollection());
$toolbar->toHtml();
?>
```

but it also return empty string. 
What is right way to output toolbar in custom position? Thank you

Comment: Check your page template, i.e. page/1column.phtml, make sure that the breadcrumbs is in echoed.

Comment: breadcrumbs is ok, toolbar block doesn't appear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem was in extension Sugarcode_Bestsellersort so disabled it in xml and I got happiness. Now fully working answer.

local.xml

```
<catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="toolbar_only" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar_only.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml"></block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <name>product_list_toolbar</name>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="breadcrumbs">
            <block type="catalog/product_list" name="toolbar_only" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar_only.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml"></block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <name>product_list_toolbar</name>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
```

toolbar_only.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

breadcrumbs.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('toolbar_only'); ?>
```